# ngBootstrap typeahead object is coming as input value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ng-bootstrap, typeahead

I am using `NgBootstrap` `TypeAhead` for integrating a lookup inside the form. I have the `items` json as follows:

```
type Item = {name: string, description: string};

const items:Item[] = [
    {"name":"NAME-1", "description":"Description -1"},
    {"name":"NAME-2", "description":"Description -2"},
]
```

and have a formatter like :

```
 formatter = (item: Item) => {
     return item.name;     
 }
```

and for the HTML I have added :

```
<input 
    id="typeahead-focus" 
    type="text" [formControlName]="idx" 
    (selectItem)="selectedItem($event, idx)" 
    [ngbTypeahead]="ItemSearch" 
    [inputFormatter]="formatter" 
    [resultFormatter]="formatter" 
    [editable]='false' 
/>
```

It is working fine, but I have one problem in submitting the form. I only need the `name` index as the value of the input field. But it is submitting the complete JSON object, which is not needed. How to fix this ?

Comment: can you add a minimal reproducible snippet ?

Answer (score 1):

you can simply, in submit, before send to the service, get the value

```
submit(form)
{
   if (form.valid)
      form.value.idx=form.value.idx.name
}
```

Another aproach is use an auxiliar variable "model" and use [ngModel] and (ngModelChange) like

```
<input id="typeahead-template" type="text" class="form-control"
        [ngModel]="model"  
        (ngModelChange)="model=$event;
           form.get('idx').setValue($event['name'])"
        [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}"
        [ngbTypeahead]="search" [resultTemplate]="rt"
        [inputFormatter]="formatter" />
```

be carefully, if you use this, when create the form you need give value also to "model"

Comment: yeah. But it is not good to use `ngModal` along with `formControlName` right ? I am using the `FormArray` here so not sure, I can remove the `formControlName`

Comment: No, you can NOT use [(ngModel)] and formControlName in the **same input**, but is correct use [(ngModel)] in a variable that NOT belong to the formControl (imagine e.g. you want to has a check-box to invisible/visible a group of inputs).NOTE: if you are using a formArray take carefully how "reach" the control